# Ruby on Rails classes and attributes initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this service class in RoR:

```
class PaypalService
  attr_reader :api  

  def initialize()        
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
    puts "PaypalService initilized"   
  end 


  # Paypal setExpressCheckout
  def self.setExpressCheckout(billingType, returnURL, cancelURL, amount, description, isRecurring, locale)     

    new                        

    if billingType == "credit-card"
      billingType = "Billing"
    else 
      billingType = "Login"
    end

    if isRecurring    
      varSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = createSetExpressCheckoutRecurringRequestDetails(billingType, returnURL, cancelURL, amount, description, isRecurring, locale)
    else
      varSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = createSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails(billingType, returnURL, cancelURL, amount, description, isRecurring, locale)
    end

    @set_express_checkout = @api.build_set_express_checkout(varSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails)
...
```

My call to the service is:

I want to initilize the @api attribute and use it whenever I execute one service method. This is my call from the client controller:

```
expressCheckoutResponse = PaypalService.setExpressCheckout(params[:paymentType], 
                                                             "http://" + Yanpy::IP + "/app/index.html#/boat-booking-payment", 
                                                             "http://" + Yanpy::IP + "/app/index.html#/boat-booking", 
                                                             totalPrice,                                                  
                                                             description,
                                                             false,
                                                             'ES')
```

Log output:

```
PaypalService initilized
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 625ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `build_set_express_checkout' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/paypal_service.rb:30:in `setExpressCheckout'
  app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:275:in `create'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def self.setExpressCheckout` this is singleton method of the class `PaypalService`. Inside of which, `@api` is an instance variable, you are trying to access, is actually the instance varoable of the class `PaypalService`, not the instance variable of the instances  `PaypalService`. As you didn't create any object of the class  `PaypalService`, thus `@api`, which you are trying to aceess still not created, and eve-if you create it, you wouldn't be able to access it from the singleton methods of the class `PaypalService`, like you did.

Example :

```
class Foo
  @x = 10
  def self.class_instance_var
    puts @x
  end
  def set_instance_var
    @x = 12
  end
  def instance_var_of_instance
     puts @x
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.set_instance_var
foo.instance_var_of_instance # => 12
Foo.class_instance_var # => 10
```

What you see, `@x` is an instance variable, of-course. But one is class `Foo`s instance variable, and the other is instances of `Foo`, like `foo`s instance variable. Name is same, bot those 2 `@x` has 2 different owners.